# Problem numbering equations properly

Tags: equations, numbering, captions, amsmath

I'm trying to create some equations with amsmath with captions and references.  I'd like to suppress the equation number in the margin.  I know this can be done using the equation* environment but this seems to have issues for the reference numbers.  When I use equation* the references read "Subsection 1.1" etc.  Further, multiple equations in the same subsection have the same reference ("Subsection 1.1")

Using \nonumbering on the line with the margin number also seems not to work.  It appears to keep the equation counter from incrementing and all equations are labeled "Equation 1"

I'd prefer to avoid using floats if possible.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Details}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{More Details}

\lipsum[1]

% Equation 1
\begin{equation*} \label{eq:myFirstEq}
y = mx + b
\end{equation*}

% I want a caption below the equation
\begin{center} 
\textbf{\autoref{eq:myFirstEq} - My Equation}
\end{center}

% Equation 2
\begin{equation*} \label{eq:mySecondEq}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation*}

\begin{center} 
\textbf{\autoref{eq:mySecondEq} - Another Equation}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

I'm going to reference \autoref{eq:myFirstEq} and \autoref{eq:mySecondEq} here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: To what are you expecting to refer, if there is no number?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind "not numbering an equation" and then using `\label` to reference it. What should `\ref` return if there is no number associated with the equation?

Comment: what he want is make equation as figure and table with label below

Comment: I mistakenly thought equation* was suppressing the display of the equation number only.  The goal was not to suppress numbering of the equation, but rather to suppress the display of the equation number to the right of the equation. The answer below worked.

Comment: It seems you are after a different way of labeling equations (with a number and "caption" below instead of the traditional number to the right). You don't want to _suppress_ the number to the right, but instead relocate it and add some additional info around it.

Comment: @PaulGessler Correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no sense for me to refer to unnumbered equations, anyway this can be done by redefining `\tagform@` (which is the command that typesets the equation number) to do nothing.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\relax}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Details}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{More Details}

\lipsum[1]

% Equation 1
\begin{equation} \label{eq:myFirstEq}
y = mx + b
\end{equation}

% I want a caption below the equation
\begin{center}
\textbf{\autoref{eq:myFirstEq} - My Equation}
\end{center}

% Equation 2
\begin{equation} \label{eq:mySecondEq}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\autoref{eq:mySecondEq} - Another Equation}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

I'm going to reference \autoref{eq:myFirstEq} and \autoref{eq:mySecondEq} here.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want captions for your equations, you can adopt this way.

Load the `float` package and define

```
\newfloat{floatequ}{H}{loe}
\floatname{floatequ}{Equation}
```

Now encase every `equation` in the `floatequ` environment.

About the formatting of the caption, I think you need

```
\captionsetup[floatequ]{font=bf,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{caption,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfloat{floatequ}{H}{loe}
\floatname{floatequ}{Equation}
\captionsetup[floatequ]{font=bf,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\relax}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Details}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{More Details}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{floatequ}
% Equation 1
\begin{equation} \label{eq:myFirstEq}
y = mx + b
\end{equation}
\caption{My equation}
\end{floatequ}

\begin{floatequ}
% Equation 2
\begin{equation} \label{eq:mySecondEq}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\caption{Another equation}
\end{floatequ}

\lipsum[1]

I'm going to reference \autoref{eq:myFirstEq} and \autoref{eq:mySecondEq} here.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want, you can also print the list of equations by adding

```
\listof{floatequ}{List of Equations}
```

[image]

---

Note that, since I've defined the `floatequ` environment to accept only the `H` floating specifier, it is not allowed to float.

Comment: I think what the OP's ask is what your answer give but without \begin{center}
\textbf{\autoref{eq:mySecondEq} - Another Equation}
\end{center} that shoud by in the equation definition

Comment: Think about what happens here if a page break falls between the "paragraphs" that shouldn't really be paragraphs.

Comment: @karlkoeller i post an answer in my sense but just like your's if you edit your answer to do what i propose i'll delete mine

Comment: @karlkoeller try to replace the first \lipsum[1] by \lipsum[1-2]

Comment: @agf If you want equation captions, see the edit

Comment: @karlkoeller good solution (+1)

Comment: @agf1997 You're welcome... once more :)